# Gradle missing dynamic task

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, finalizer, gradle-task

I have a declared task:

```
tasks.getByName('connectedAndroidTest').finalizedBy 'archiveReports'
```

But when I am trying to build project it tells me that:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'connectedAndroidTest' not found in project ':TestProject'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultTaskCollection.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:229)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskCollection.getByName(DefaultTaskCollection.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskCollection$getByName.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_6w8zk6ic8wtqwlvwwubix2jc3.run(/path/to/build.gradle:84)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 58 more
```

If I change it to other way:

```
tasks.connectedAndroidTest.finalizedBy 'archiveReports'
```

The issue is very similar:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'connectedAndroidTest' for task set.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at build_6w8zk6ic8wtqwlvwwubix2jc3.run(/path/to/build.gradle:84)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 58 more
```

I understand that this task is generated dynamically due to flavour, but how to add a finalizer to dynamic task?

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @matrix unfortunately, no

Comment: actually I have done this: `task printEspressoResults(dependsOn: 'connectedAndroidTest') ` and when I run `gradlew printEspressoResults` it executed `connectedAndroidTest` first and then `printEspressoResults`. Hope it helps someone else